# Term for "Massively Multiscale world browsing"?

Tags: simulations, interface, visualization

There is a type of multi-scale world browsing that has appeared in games in the last few years and I would be interested to know if there is a specific term that this browsing is known as and more importantly, if there are already specific patterns or techniques for implementing it.

I am referring to games like:

- [Universe Sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_Sandbox)
- [EVE online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eve_Online)
- [Startrek Armada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Armada)
- [Heat Signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_Signature_(video_game))

The common characteristic of these games is that they allow you to zoom across an incredible range of scale from "item" all the way out to "galaxy" without (apparent) loss of synchronisation between what is happening at each scale. So, it looks like the world "advances" across all of these different scales simultaneously. Also, it is likely that each browsing level is a different visualisation type which is then blended seamlessly by matching the camera viewpoints and "cutting" from one level to the next but that might just be my perception.

What I am specifically interested to know would be:

1. If this technique has a name already (?)
2. If there is a ready made component (or pattern) that sorts out the architecture for achieving this kind of browsing (?)
3. If the "world" is really simulated at all levels (?)